# How do you get all of the top N types within an ordered MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assume I have a collection that looks something like this:

```js
[{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'foo',
    value: 123,
    date: '2022-06-30',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'bar',
    value: 321,
    date: '2022-06-29',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'foo',
    value: 456,
    date: '2022-06-28',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'bar',
    value: 789,
    date: '2022-06-27',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'baz',
    value: 234,
    date: '2022-06-26',
},
// etc....
]
```

It's sorted by date.

I want to get all of the top items of the first 2 types as they appear.  In this case, that means I want to get everything above the last item shown, which is of type "baz", the third type to exist after type "foo" and "bar".

```js
// Expected result
[{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'foo',
    value: 123,
    date: '2022-06-30',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'bar',
    value: 321,
    date: '2022-06-29',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'foo',
    value: 456,
    date: '2022-06-28',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'bar',
    value: 789,
    date: '2022-06-27',
}]
```

Assuming this new item is added to the collection:

```js
{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'baz',
    value: 567,
    date: '2022-07-01',
}
```

The new expected result would be

```js
[{
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'baz',
    value: 567,
    date: '2022-07-01',
}, {
    _id: new ObjectId(),
    type: 'foo',
    value: 123,
    date: '2022-06-30',
}]
```

...as "bar" from `2022-06-29` would now be the third type to appear in the ordered set.

Comment: please define "top" and "above". Does it mean "latest" or do you do some aggregation?

Comment: In this case, assume that this collection is sorted by date and the sample is the result set in the aggrigation pipeline.  For example:

`someCollection.aggregate([{ $sort: {date:  -1}}])`

Comment: It would be quite heavy aggregation as you will need to scan whole collection once to determine the stop point, then query it again to get latest documents. It would be way simpler to do on application level - just close the cursor once you received a document with 3rd type

Comment: nimrod serok provided an answer using the $setWindowFields operator, which I was previously unaware of.  That said, it's possible I end up ultimately doing this, depending on the performance implications of that one on larger datasets.

Comment: Changing "it's possible" to "will".  It's an interesting and cleaver query that does precisely what I asked.  But with a large number of "type"s (which will apply in my case, though not specified in my post), this would be impractical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mongoDB version 5.0 you can use `$setWindowFields` for this:

1. The `$setWindowFields` allows to sort according to the `date` and add a new field to each document, with a set of the `type`s "so far".
2. Now we just need to match only documents with less than 3 `topTypes`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {date: -1},
      output: {
        topTypes: {
          $addToSet: "$type",
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {$expr: {$lt: [{$size: "$topTypes"}, 3]}}
  },
  {
    $unset: "topTypes"
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jiyugtZT5I5)

Comment: Thanks so much.  Messing with the playground example link you provided, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: After poking at this and understanding what the first stage is doing, it seems that manually pulling records until I get the third type (for this case) might be the more practical approach as this result appends an unbounded array to each record. This still answers the specific question I asked and introduced me to another tool for my mongo toolset. This will remain the checked answer.

Thanks again!